# match filenames to foldernames then move files

Tags: python, regex

I have files named "a1.txt", "a2.txt", "a3.txt", "a4.txt", "a5.txt" and so on. Then I have folders named "a1_1998", "a2_1999", "a3_2000", "a4_2001", "a5_2002" and so on.

I would like to make the conection between file "a1.txt" & folder "a1_1998" for example. (I'm guessing I'll need a regular expresion to do this). then use shutil to move file "a1.txt" into folder "a1_1998", file "a2.txt" into folder "a2_1999" etc....

I've started like this but I'm stuck because of my lack of understanding of regular expresions.

```
import re
##list files and folders

r = re.compile('^a(?P') 
m = r.match('a') 
m.group('id')

##
##Move files to folders
```

I modified the answer below slightly to use shutil to move the files, did the trick!!

```
import shutil
import os
import glob 

files = glob.glob(r'C:\Wam\*.txt')

for file in files: 
    # this will remove the .txt extension and keep the "aN"  
    first_part = file[7:-4]
    # find the matching directory 
    dir = glob.glob(r'C:\Wam\%s_*/' % first_part)[0]
    shutil.move(file, dir)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need regular expressions for this.

How about something like this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in files:
    # this will remove the .txt extension and keep the "aN" 
    first_part = file[:-4]
    # find the matching directory
    dir = glob.glob('%s_*/' % first_part)[0]
    os.rename(file, os.path.join(dir, file))
```

Comment: this solution is very specific to the answer, and is not the best way to do this. you should use `os.path.splitext()` to get the `(filename, extension)` pair.

Comment: @Inbar Rose, `splitext()` is the more general solution in case you need to remove the extension from the filename. However, I am not sure that this will always be the case. The OP did not specify that.

Comment: this assumes that the files and folders are in the same dir. more than that, it also assumes all the folders are in the same dir. there should be a dictionary in the form of `{'a1':"folder/path/to/a1_1998", 'a2':"folder/path/to/a2_1999"}`.... taking a slice from a string is not indicative of what you are actually doing, in this case, the OP was clear that he wants filenames to go into their folders. also - `os.rename` is not always the best to use, imho `shutil.move` is better.

Comment: Thanks all managed to combine Hans's answer with shutil.move to move the files, fantastic!! (As posted above). would vote up but sorry not enough rep by two points

Answer (score 0):

A slight alternative, taking into account Inbar Rose's suggestion.

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.txt')
dirs = glob.glob('*_*')

for file in files:
  filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
  matchdir = next(x for x in dirs if filename == x.rsplit('_')[0])
  os.rename(file, os.path.join(matchdir, file))
```

Comment: Thanks Talvalin this should do the trick, I'm just having trouble with the matchdir line when I add the path to my files as shown below: import os 
import glob 
 
files = glob.glob(r'C:\Wam\*.docx') 
dirs = glob.glob(r'C:\Wam\*_*') 
 
is there another way to specify the working directory?

Comment: Using double quotes to specify the directories should fix that. eg: files = glob.glob("C:\Wam*.docx")