# python - find filenames different than foldername

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, bigdata

My company have files named

```
"3688-35(DUSTY GREY-BLK).jpg"
"3688-36A(SLIVER).jpg"
"..."
```

which should be placed at "**3688**" folder.

after years and years I'm facing *6 digits pictures and ~3500 folders* with countless misplaced pictures need to be checked is placed in right folder,

So I think I can write a script can list only wrong placed files and folder like

```
"1111/1112.jpg"
"1234/1243.jpg"
```

after I do some search I find [match filenames to foldernames then move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930303/match-filenames-to-foldernames-then-move-files) is kind of what I need but I cannot modify the answer to my need because the filename pattern.

I stuck at first but I think https://pymotw.com/2/glob/ can do some trick on listing and with https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

```
from glob import glob
import logging, time, os

def listdirs(path):
    return [d for d in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(d)]

def find_pics():
    folders = listdirs(".")
    for dir in folders:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        pics = os.listdir(dir)
        for pic in pics:
            if pic.endswith(".jpg"):
                if dir not in pic:
                    logging.warning(dir + ' / ' + pic)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
    return

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='wrong_placed.log', filemode='w', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s \n')
    logging.debug("Starting to check is the picture wrong placed.")
    find_pics()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```